# ¿cómo insertar el valor en una columna si se cumpre una condición en r?

Tags: base-de-datos, r, datatables, tablas, agrupación

espero me puedan ayudar con el siguiente problema por favor.

Tengo una **tabla 1** de *codigos y referencias*, ej. auto = automovil, bici = bicicleta, moto = motocicleta.

Y tengo otra **tabla 2** que tiene más filas con más  *codigos* (ej. auto, auto, bici, moto, moto, bic, auto, auto) pero sin *referencias*.

Mi problema es que no se como agregar las *referencias* de la **tabla 1** (automovil, bicicleta, motocicleta) a todos los *codigos* de la **tabla 2**

Para que mi resultado sea en la **tabla 2**: ej. auto = automovil, auto = automovil, bici = bicicleta, moto = motocicleta, moto = motocicleta, etc..

Answer (score 1):

Entiendo que tienes las siguientes tablas:

```
df<-data.frame(codigo=c("auto", "bici", "moto"), referencia=c("Automovil","Bicicleta", "Motocicleta"))
df
  codigo  referencia
1   auto   Automovil
2   bici   Bicicleta
3   moto Motocicleta

# Y la siguiente tabla.
df1<-data.frame(code=c("auto", "auto", "bici", "moto", "moto", "bici", "auto", "auto"))
df1
  code
1 auto
2 auto
3 bici
4 moto
5 moto
6 bici
7 auto
8 auto
```

Entonces, si tu deseas agregar en la segunda tabla el valor de referencia de la primera tabla, tendrías que hacer un `join`, especificamente un `left`. Con el siguiente código.

```
library(dplyr)

df1<-left_join(df1,df, by=c("code"="codigo"))
```

Lo que te quedará, de la siguiente manera:

```
  code  referencia
1 auto   Automovil
2 auto   Automovil
3 bici   Bicicleta
4 moto Motocicleta
5 moto Motocicleta
6 bici   Bicicleta
7 auto   Automovil
8 auto   Automovil
```

Espero haya podido ayudarte.